# Shutdown in linux without sudo

Tags: linux

I am making a project in linux which needs to shutdown the system when process is finished. How can it be done without the need to provide password?

Answer (score 2):

If your program (e.g. in C, C++, Ocaml, ...) is compiled into an ELF executable you could make it [**setuid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) (then use [seteuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html),  [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html), [reboot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html) syscalls, or better yet [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) on `/sbin/poweroff`or other commands). But be careful (be afraid of [security holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_%28computing%29), ...)

You'll need to **code your program very carefully**, and you'll need to be root to install your program with the setuid bit set (e.g. `chmod u+s` as root). But users won't need to be root to run the installed executable.

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (and carefully several man pages for important [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)). Please take time to understand the *setuid* mechanism, which is tricky and can be used dangerously.

And you could simply install and configure your system to start your program as root (e.g. by configuring your `init` or `systemd`, or some `crontab`, or some startup in `/etc/rc.local` etc etc etc ...)

Read also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

Comment: This is an interesting concept and works. You can hard compile the shutdown command in the c code. Not at all tricky to program, since the code would run only the shutdown command.

Answer (score 2):

On distributions with recent `systemd`, it is possible to shut down the system if no other user is logged in. This requires however a full-blown login session via systemd-logind, of which I don’t know whether you have it.

If your process lives in such an environment, you can call `systemctl poweroff` or `systemctl reboot`. The context of your process (running in a full blown login session, if no other user is logged in) will allow you to shut the system down.

Comment: Did you mean `systemctl poweroff/reboot`?

Comment: Eh right, of course.

Comment: If `systemctl poweroff` is not available, also try `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop`

Answer (score 0):

If you use visudo and add

```
%group_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

you can use shutdown without providing a password.
However you will still need sudo.
But you could create an alias in .bashrc which replaces sudo shutdown now with shutdown

How to create an alias:
    http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/891

of course this works with every other command as well

Comment: It still asks password. Tried in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: is the user, you are trying this with in the group?

Comment: Does it matter, since this line is granting every group access to the command? But yes, the user has sudo rights

Comment: I created a new user bob and a group test on a ubuntu 16.04 vm.
Afterwards i added `%test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/visudo` to the sudoers file. Now bob can run `sudo visudo` without entering a password.
You only grant access to the group group_name, in my example bob is not in sudo group

Comment: Well, does that mean it won't work for a person already in the sudoers group?

Comment: if there are multiple line matching the user the last one will be the one which applies. If you put this line as the last in the sudoer file you should be good to go